# What is the name of this line in a letter . e.g we have subject etc?

Tags: british-english, letter-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it appropriate to use the salutation “Dear All” in a work email?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292/is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-salutation-dear-all-in-a-work-email)

> Dear Mr.Dandy Rabbit, <----------------- What is the name of this line
>
> I hereby wish to advise that we are out of carrots .
>
> ................

What is the name of this line in a letter . e.g we have subject etc .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you want is **Salutation**.

Comment: I was thinking the same but would not that be `MR` or `Dr` etc.

Comment: 'Mr', 'Dr', 'Captain', or other titles that you might use to precede someones name are **honorifics**.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42598/8019